# JS match data between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 arrays and need to match data from them. I need to get `ID` from first array and `market_name` from second array. I need to use these 2 arrays, even if `wgg` array looks irrelevant. Im using `if` to match data: `item.market_name == wgg[j].market_name` it works well, but if there are more than 1 value with same `market_name` like below, it prints all same Id for them all. For example, this what it prints:

```
 market_name | ID
        John | 151
        John | 151
        John | 151
        Sam  | 115
    Somebody | 110
```

First array (item):

```
 market_name | ID
        John | 151
        John | 100
        John | 180
        Sam  | 115
    Somebody | 110
```

Second array (wgg[j]):

```
 market_name | ID
        John | 105
        John | 209
        John | 401
        Sam  | 115
    Somebody | 110
```

How it should be:

```
 market_name | ID
        John | 151
        John | 100
        John | 180
        Sam  | 115
    Somebody | 110
```

JS:

```
tradedata.forEach(function(item, j) {
    var resultas = tradedata.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.market_name == wgg[j].market_name) {
                assetas = item.id;
                return assetas;
            }
    });

if (resultas.length > 0) {
console.log(wgg[j].market_name);
console.log(assetas);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are equaling them both with `return item.market_name == wgg[j].market_name;` how it shouldn't return the same data?

Comment: @developer I tried `return assetas;` but its same.

Comment: If what you're asking is, how do I find the first element in an array that matches, look at Array.prototype.indexOf() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: the `required` output looks identical to the first array - how does the wgg array effect the output?

Comment: wgg array is used for market_name, item array is for ID.

Comment: yes, you say that, but the output is identical to the input, wgg looks irrelevant. Perhaps you need a better example, because your description of what you want does not match your example of what you want

Comment: First `wgg` array needs to match `market_name` with `item` array, and then use `market_name` from `wgg` and `ID` from `item` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you describe

```
var tradedata = [
    { market_name: 'John', id: 151},
    { market_name: 'John', id: 100},
    { market_name: 'John', id: 180},
    { market_name: 'Sam', id: 115},
    { market_name: 'Somebody', id: 110}
];
var wgg = [
    { market_name: 'John', id: 105},
    { market_name: 'John', id: 209},
    { market_name: 'John', id: 401},
    { market_name: 'Sam', id: 115},
    { market_name: 'Somebody', id: 110}
];

var result = wgg.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    if (!obj.names[item.market_name]) {
        obj.names[item.market_name] = true;
        obj.data = obj.data.concat(tradedata.filter(function(trade) {
                return trade.market_name == item.market_name;
            })
        );
    }
    return obj;
}, {names:{}, data:[]}).data;

result.forEach(function(x) {
    console.log(x);    
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it works. Can you answer my question? Im using mysql 3 actions in result.forEach. Sometimes, when for example there are like 15 values in array, 1 of 3 mysql actions just dont execute (only once of 15 times). It happens really rarely. I was using for() before without any problems. What can be problem? I know its not much information, but maybe you have experience with this.

Comment: I know javascript ... I don't know mysql